# Clockwork Ruby Gem: How to restart?

Tags: ruby, clockwork

How does one restart the Ruby clockwork gem?

After reading the Wiki, it seems you can only start it, not stop or restart it.

I don't want to manually kill the process and run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you started it as a daemon, then 'clockworkd -c YOUR_CLOCK.rb stop' should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The modern syntax to restart clockworkd is:

```
bin/clockworkd -c periodic-jobs.rb reload
```

If you've bundled your gems, as you should:

```
bundle exec bin/clockworkd -c periodic-jobs.rb reload
```

…where `periodic-jobs.rb` is your clockwork jobs config file.

Full options:

```
bin/clockworkd help
Usage: clockworkd -c FILE [options] start|stop|restart|run

        --pid-dir=DIR                Alternate directory in which to store the process ids. Default is /Users/jm3/Code/soakcity/tmp.
    -i, --identifier=STR             An identifier for the process. Default is clock file name.
    -l, --log                        Redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to a logfile named clockworkd[.<identifier>].output in the pid-file directory.
        --log-dir=DIR                A specific directory to put the log files into (default location is pid directory).
    -m, --monitor                    Start monitor process.
    -c, --clock=FILE                 Clock .rb file. Default is /Users/jm3/Code/soakcity/clock.rb.
    -d, --dir=DIR                    Directory to change to once the process starts
    -h, --help                       Show this message
```

Learn more in the [Demonization](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork#daemonization) section of the clockwork source on GitHub. Hope that helps!